# Can you change the number of icons In the 'quick settings' tray (Android Oreo)

Tags: 8.0-oreo, quick-settings

Oreo has reduced the number of icons in the quick settings tray from 9 to 6. Is it possible to adjust the number of icons shown, e.g. to 6 or 12?

Edit: Just to clarify: I mean the layout of the drawer, e.g. 3x2 (Oreo) vs. 3x3 (Nougat) vs. 4x2 (Samsung). I don't mean the total number of icons shown, including the icons accesses by swiping left/right.

Comment: Not in pure AOSP Android, but maybe... What device specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Use "System UI Tuner" app which found on Google Play Store. It need some permissions from ADB. Dont worry that describes within the App

Comment: The app can customise many settings, but I was specifically wondering whether you can change the layout - from 3x2, to 3x3 (as it was in nougat) or e.g. 4x2 (Samsung). I couldn't see that in the screenshots of the app